# Some column Missing Bottom border in material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, border, tablecell

I have set the table Cell borders set to solid and 1 pixel.  The data for the table covers many pages and some columns in a row do not show the bottom border, Every row is rendered by the same element and every column has same class.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxMqD.png)

What do I have to do to get this border to show?

Comment: The grey borders are visible perfectly. Do you mean the pink area? Maybe you can't notice them because the colors are similar. Try to make the border black and check again if everything is okay.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.